# Atribuição de function Jquery para ImageButton

Tags: jquery, button

Bom dia!

Como posso atribuir uma function Jquery para um imagem buttom ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho essa linha de código que é pra exportar um relatório em excel e quero chamar uma function Jquery para carregar uma tela de processando enquanto o servidor faz todas as validações necessárias.

Ex.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs. Eu já tenho a function em outras telas e, já verifiquei que funciona no "button" normal,já tentei chamar essa function no evento do button, mas não funciona como esse "ImageButton".

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se eu entendi bem o que vc falou mas vc pode colocar a function no atributo OnClientClick ou fazer diretamente no JQuery

Tipo isso:

```js
$("#<%=btnImpListaXLS.ClientID%>").click(function(){
  
});
```

Obs: esse ClientID do JQuery só funciona na própria página ASP. Se estiver em outra página precisa chamar por classe.